# Smooth a density plot so that it doesn't appear saw toothed

Tags: r, smoothing, density-plot

I have made a density plot in R. I want to get rid of the saw tooth pattern and have it be entirely smooth. The reason that it appears saw tooth is because the values of x$PLCO2 are all whole numbers. But I want to smooth the plot for aesthetic reasons. Any idea on how to do that?

```
plot(density(x$PLCO2))
```

[image: Density Plot]

Comment: Hi, you can change the wandwidth by increasing **bw**, it will make the density smoother.

Comment: @MamounBenghezal Thanks that did it! If you put your answer below I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can make you density plot smoother by increasing the **bandwidth** (bw)

```
plot(density(x$PLCO2, bw = bw_bigger))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `adjust`.

```
plot(density(x$PLCO2, adjust = 2))
```

The [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/density) say:

> `adjust`: the bandwidth used is actually `adjust*bw`. This makes it easy
>   to specify values like ‘half the default’ bandwidth.